# Referring to a passed Enum's properties without knowing its type

Tags: c#, class, enums

I have a series of enums that correspond to numeric IDs used in a database, i.e. ...

```
public enum ResponseType1 {
    Accept = 10
    Reject = 11 };

public enum ResponseType2 {
    Accept = 12
    Reject = 13 };

public enum ResponseType3 {
    Accept = 14
    Reject = 15 };
```

A class has a 'ResponseTypeEnum' property of type Object that gets set at runtime and will be one of the various response type enums ...

```
MyClass.ResponseTypeEnum = ResponseType2
```

I know that all of the response type enums will have both an Accept and Reject value, so what I'd like to know is whether it's possible to refer to an enum's value by name without knowing its type, i.e. once I've assigned ResponseType2 to the ResponseTypeEnum property of my class is there a way of referring to the Reject value of that enum, i.e. ...

```
MyClass.ResponseTypeEnum.Reject
```

In this case the parsed value would 11, 13, or 15 depending on which enum I assigned to the ResponseTypeEnum property.

Is this possible? And, crucially, is this good practise? Any better way of achieving this?

Comment: Wouldn't a much better solution to have a ResponseTypeBase class?

Comment: Can you clarify with an example Jamie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea.

I would create a class `ResponseType` with two properties `Accept` and `Reject`.
Furthermore I would create three derived classes that set those properties to the correct values:

```
public abstract class ResponseType
{
    private readonly int _accept;
    private readonly int _reject;

    protected ResponseType(int accept, int reject)
    {
        _accept = accept;
        _reject = reject;
    }

    public int Accept { get { return _accept; } }
    public int Reject { get { return _reject; } }
}

public class ResponseType1 : ResponseType
{
    public ResponseType1() : base(10, 11) { }
}

public class ResponseType2 : ResponseType
{
    public ResponseType2() : base(12, 13) { }
}

public class ResponseType3 : ResponseType
{
    public ResponseType3() : base(14, 15) { }
}
```

`MyClass.ResponseTypeEnum` should be renamed to `MyClass.ResponseType` and changed to be of type `ResponseType`.

Usage would now be like this:

```
MyClass.ResponseType = new ResponseType1();
```

You can use `MyClass.ResponseType` in a `switch` statement without problems:

```
switch(databaseValue)
{
    case MyClass.ResponseType.Accept:
        // accept
        break;
    case MyClass.ResponseType.Reject:
        // reject
        break;
}
```

Comment: The response type that's assigned to the class will be used in Switch statements. I want to keep this strongly typed, so I'm hoping to be able to write something along the lines of ...

    `switch (myDatabaseValue)
    {
    case MyClass.ResponseType.Accept:
        ' do something
    case MyClass.ResponseType.Reject:
        ' do something else
    case MyClass.ResponectType.Other:
        ' Some other action
    }`

Comment: Why aren't my code blocks formatted properly when added to a comment?! I can't get carriage returns to appear?

Comment: @RCW: That would still work, exactly the same, please see update.

Comment: @RCW: Comments are not meant for long discussions, that's why they lack certain features on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

You could have ResponseTypeEnum as a dynamic type.

> is this good practise?

I would not recommend it

> Any better way of achieving this?

Yes. You can use a more explicit class structure here eg.

```
class Response
{ 
  enum type;
  bool accept;
}
```